# Count Print Report In JDE (RDA)

Tags: jdeveloper, jdedwards

Have any of you can provide me some idea about how to check how many times the report have been print by different user_ID in JDE (RDA)? Based on what I knew the print count system function was use to determine how many page of the report and not how many times the report have been printed. Is that any system function that I can use to find out how many times the report has been printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a query on the job control status table (F986110) to see how many times the report has ran. Here is the query you need to use:

```
select count(1) from SVM812.F986110 where JCFNDFUF2 like 'REPORTNAME%';
```

You can of course code a business function that would return a count based on a report id parameter.

Happy coding